# SQL: Finding duplicates in large table

Tags: sql, duplicates

I have a large table called Clientescrm, it has two columns. Idclientecrm (primary key; auto_increment) and CUIT.

I want to find duplicates for CUIT, but I have two problems:

1. The format of the data may vary, sometimes it´s written like 20-12344567-6, others 20_12344567_6 or 20123446576. I want to erase all symbols to analyse the data.
2. The other thing I need is the Idclientecrm value (primary key).

I was using something like this:

```
select replace(replace(cuit, '-', ''),'_','') as cuit, count(cuit) as duplicates
from clientescrm
group by cuit
having count(cuit) > 1
```

That query lacks the primary key(idclientecrm), that I also need.

I want the result table to look something like this:

|idclientecrm|cuit         |duplicates|
|1           |20123456786  |2         |
|2           |20123456786  |2         |
|3           |23123456787  |3         |
|4           |23123456787  |3         |
|5           |23123456787  |3         |
|6           |27123456783  |2         |
|7           |27123456783  |2         |
|8           |20111111116  |3         |
|9           |20111111116  |3         |
|10          |20111111116  |3         |

Thnx in advance for your help

Comment: Add Min(idclientTerm) to the SELECT list

Comment: Which primary key do you want? Latest? Earliest? Both? You're searching for duplicates but not giving us a way to decide which of the duplicated PKs you need! I suspect if you answer this question you'll have your solution.

Comment: Is this a one time run or multiple runs?  If multiple over time, then I would recommend a function based index, if your RDBMS supports it, to strip the values for you. Queries with CUIT value compairisons will be much faster in the long run.

Comment: I want both, I want the actual data to be in the data result.

Answer (score 0):

You can take your query, add Min(idClientTerm) to the select list.   This assumes you want to keep the key with the lowest ID.   Essentially remover all records whose ID number does not appear in your query...

```
select replace(replace(cuit, '-', ''),'_','') as cuit, 
       count(*) as duplicates,min(idClientTerm) as IDtoSave
from clientescrm
group by replace(replace(cuit, '-', ''),'_','')
```

Note, I took off the **count(*) > 1**, this way, if a CUIT only appears once, it will still be included, so you don't delete the single occurrences

You would then DELETE from the table where idClientTerm not in your subquery

```
select * from clientescm
where id not in 
(
    select min(idClientTerm) as IDtoSave
    from clientescrm
    group by replace(replace(cuit, '-', ''),'_','')
)
```

Be sure to back-up your data first and I suggest running a few SELECT query to make sure the list of ID's you'll keep look proper

Comment: I don't want to erase data, I want to know which two, three or one hundred idclientecrm's have the same CUIT.

Comment: I changed the answer to use a SELECT statement.   The inner query returns either the ID's with no dupes or the lowest ID if a dupe occurs.   If an ID is not in the list generated by the inner query, it has dupes

Answer (score 0):

With joining the original table to your query?
Like this:

```
select
 a.cuit,
 a.duplicates,
 c.Idclientecrm
from
(
   select
      replace(replace(cuit, '-', ''),'_','') as cuit,
      count(cuit) as duplicates
   from clientescrm
   group by cuit
   having count(cuit) > 1
) a,
Clientescrm c
where
a.cuit= replace(replace(c.cuit, '-', ''),'_','')
```

Comment: what is the error message? (The inner query should be the same as yours, if I made a typo maybe...)

Comment: It's telling me the table clientescrm doesn't exists

Comment: I copied this table name from your post/queries. Could you please change it to your table's name?

Comment: The names are correct and all the table exist, I only changed the x for a letter "a", and also changed the x after the ) that closes the other select.

Comment: Haven't you forgot the where x.cuit part? I changed the table alias to a everywhere in the answer.

Comment: select
 a.cuit,
 a.duplicates,
 c.Idclientecrm
from
(
   select
      replace(replace(cuit, '-', ''),'_','') as cuit,
      count(cuit) as duplicates
   from clientescrm
   group by cuit
   having count(cuit) > 1
) a,
Clientescrm c
where
a.cuit = replace(replace(c.cuit, '-', ''),'_','')

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44429/discussion-between-lajos-veres-and-pietro)

Answer (score 0):

You need to place the replace in your groupby aswell. 
Any result you see occurs more then once in your table. 
It seems that is what your looking for.

```
select replace(replace(cuit, '-', ''),'_','') as cuit, count(*)
    from clientescrm
    group by replace(replace(cuit, '-', ''),'_','')
    having count(*) > 1
```